# Github actions : how can I setup pypy environment?

Tags: github, mingw, github-actions

I would like to run scripts with pypy interpreter ,along with build some C++ code into binaries with minGW. According to official documentation `https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md` ,both pypy and minGW should be pre installed when I start a windows server workflow.

However I couldn't find neither pypy or minGW (via command `gcc -v` and `pypy -V`).
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an example](https://github.com/pjquirk/actions-test-004/blob/master/.github/workflows/pythonpackage.yml) of a workflow that finds both:

```yaml
name: Python package

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: pypy3
    - name: pypy absolute path
      run: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\PyPy\3.6.9\x86\pypy3 -v
    - name: pypy in path
      run: pypy3 -v
    - name: Look for mingw
      run: gcc --version
```

See the [output here](https://github.com/pjquirk/actions-test-004/runs/486641227?check_suite_focus=true).  You didn't list your original workflow but I imagine you got tripped up with specifying the python version.  The [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-python-with-github-actions#using-multiple-python-versions) lists separate versions for python and pypy.